# Creating Dictionary from dictionary formatted string? using python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, parsing

Let's say that I have a list of dictionaries that looks something like 
this in a string format

"[{key1:{key11:val11,key12:val12}},{key2:{key21:val21, key22:val22}}]"

How can i change this string(in the dictionary format) to an actual dictionary? while keeping the format?

Comment: use the json module

Comment: can you show me an example ?  using this example above?

Comment: you can check here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: i've seen the post yukun, but i'm running into this error raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn’t json data nor is it a dict it’s 2 separate dicts in a set which isn’t even correct. Although you can get both dicts as a tuple using `ast.literal_eval` if you format it correctly which can be done using `re`

```
data = "{{key1:{key11:val11,key12:val12}},{key2:{key21:val21, key22:val22}}}"
dicts = ast.literal_eval(re.sub(r'(\w+)', r'"\1"', data [1:-1]))
```

Result:

```
({'key1': {'key11': 'val11', 'key12': 'val12'}}, {'key2': {'key21': 'val21', 'key22': 'val22'}})
```

Comment: hi Jab, what if it is in the format of,
"[{key1:{key11:val11,key12:val12}},{key2:{key21:val21, key22:val22}}]"? a list of dict per say

Comment: Did you try that?

Comment: It worked fine for me with the input in your comment.

Comment: You just need to remove the slicing to get it as a list

Comment: if you slice the string, don't you still get the string?